# Middle click on an <a> tag in chrome not working when using eval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

My menu structure is as follows

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" rel="profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" rel="settings">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Whenever I click the  tag my function gets the rel attribute and I run an eval() function on it i.e.

```
$('ul li a').die('click');
$(document).on('click','ul li a',function(event){

     eval($(this).attr('rel'))['init']();// open the settings.init() function

});
```

This works in all the browsers, However when I middle click with my mouse in Chrome the function redirects in the same window while for the other browsers it opens in a new tab

How do I get it to open in a new tab in Chrome when I middle click ?

Comment: Using `eval` like this isn't a good idea. `window[this.rel].init();` will probably work. Also, what is `settings.init`?

Comment: i have a js file called settings.js which has a function SETTINGS(){} Inside of which i have the init() and other functions

Comment: Without its source, it's hard to tell what's not working.

Comment: eval is rarely necessary. What's wrong with `try { $(this).attr('rel').init(); } catch(e){ console.log("cant call attrrel init : "+e);  }`   ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is all i have maybe i could make a jsfiddle example. But what I am trying to figure out is that the middle click works in FF it opens a new tab while in Chrome runs the function in the same tab

Comment: @Paul: `$(this).attr('rel')` returns a string, which doesn't have an `init` method.

Comment: @Neil: There's not enough info here to tell you why `.init()` doesn't work in Chrome if you don't post what `.init()` actually does.

Comment: for now I just have an alert('Hello') world happening in the init function and I update the #part of the url to to include the attr i.e setting

Comment: @Blender Ah.  So $(this).attr('rel').init is actually code that needs to be executed.

Comment: Some people say not to set event handlers or code snippets in the HTML.  Do all that in the javascript files and it turns out a lot cleaner.

Comment: Im trying to build a sort of ajax navigation without the need of the whole page refresh.  JavaScript isn't my forte

Comment: @Blender he is asking why middle click does not work, not whether using EVAL is right or wrong. May be this is part of big Logic which he has just simplified by giving a smaller example. May be he has conditional expression in rel as 'a ? settings : profile' which has to be evaluated using EVAL. It is not a good idea to blindly suggest no EVAL for all problems just because you read it in somebody's blog.

Comment: @AkashKava: I understand, but what does that function do? Does it open a new window? Does it set `window.location.href`? Does it create a new anchor element and click it? I can't telepathically tell what's wrong without seeing what does what.

Comment: @AkashKava: As for `eval`, if you're putting complex logic into the `rel` attribute of an anchor tag and then evaluating it, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Blender who says it I am doing wrong? President of JS ? I still don't care, cause he is not paying me. All and many JS frameworks are coming up with complex logic in attribute. It is about making things simpler, and not about satisfying Someone's EGO.

Comment: @AkashKava: If you don't see anything wrong with `eval`ing JavaScript code that you pulled out of a `rel` attribute (which isn't even valid HTML), there's no point in even discussing this.

Comment: @akashkava It is wrong, you know it.  Your answer talks about the right way to do it, just change the href from the handler, even if a #hash, since the OP wants Ajax navigation.  They'll need to poll for changes in the history.

Comment: @JuanMendes, Once again, if you read my argument, I am saying that we are no one to judge about using eval or not. I see a blind set of answers, dont use EVAL just become it hurts someone's ego, it is wrong. Please suggest a solution or an answer, not using eval is not a solution in anyway. Every answer in SO has one comment, using eval is bad, it is op's choice, you are not focusing on nature of problem. Middle click is not working in Chrome, thats it, why are you guys taking topic to different subject of whether eval should be used or not. The first comment does not need to be in this post.

Comment: @AkashKava: Look at the source of jQuery, Handlebars, Knockout, Backbone, Angular and any other large JavaScript project. Do you see any `eval` calls in there? No. It may be OP's choice, but if it's the wrong choice, I can tell them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all see if the event handler gets called or not. If middle click does not raise an event then it could be a bug in Browser or jQuery. I suspect that window.open method works little differently on Chrome.

To open new page in tab on a link, you can specify target='_blank' or target='tab' instead of using opening in JS. what I mean is, you can alter anchor tag itself instead of calling window.open.

```
$('a').each(
    function(){
        // some condition evaluation
    $(this).attr('href',destURL);
    $(this).attr('target','_blank');
});
```

By doing so you are simplifying code, and you could debug and see everything in element inspector.

The benefit is, if you do not specify target, user has ability to open link anywhere he/she wants.

Comment: That's correct.  The problem is that they are not using the link. It's lucky that it works in other browsers

Comment: I think it is a bug or different behaviour of different browser for window.open method, just like it has always been, W3C is sleeping and browsers add more conflicting stuff and our job becomes worse day by day.

Comment: Exactly why you shouldn't rely on it

Comment: `tab` isn't a valid value for the `target` attribute. You probably want to use `_blank` instead.

Comment: @Blender It is *valid*. It will, however, only work if there is a window open with the name `tab`.

Comment: @AkashKava I might be doing something wrong, but I feel like my job is getting better and better. There will always be differences between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're not hit by the Chrome 28 middle-click bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236835. It's fixed in Chrome 29, which is in beta now.